# Unity2D - Change Objects Trajectory if stuck on x axis

Tags: unity-game-engine, math

I am working on a little Unity game and have a problem where my game ball can hit the corner of a block at get stuck at a specific X axis since the Y axis of the object is not going up or down.

I am trying to detect this scenario, and correct it by enforcing some minimum y axis movement on the ball.[image]

The green arrow is something I added in paint and illustrates where the ball can sometimes get stuck.

I have tried logging a few different things to detect this scenario, like storing the lastY and nextY and find some sort of difference that is or is not acceptable, but I feel like this is a dirty fix.

Is there a proper way to do this?

```
    void Start()
{
    lastY = transform.position.y;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    float diff = transform.position.y - lastY;
    //Debug.Log("Last X:" + lastX + " X:" + transform.position.x);
    Debug.Log("Diff: " + diff);
    lastY = transform.position.y;
    //Debug.Log(rb.
    //Debug.Log("AV: " + rb.angularVelocity);
    //Debug.Log("RO: " + rb.rotation);
}
```

Code that kind of works at the moment

```
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    lastY = transform.position.y;
}

private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    double diff = (double)transform.position.y - lastY;
    if (diff < 0.02 && diff > -0.02)
    {
        Debug.Log("NOT ENOUGH ANGLE: " + rb.velocity.y);
        if (diff < 0)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.y - 1);
        } else
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.y +1);
        }

    }
}
```

Not very good at math so I am a little stumped.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable approach to me. Except I would use the `rb.velocity` directly instead of storing `lastY`. You might want to examine why you are getting horizontal velocities in the first place. If you only have horizontal and vertical lines, that should not happen, unless you hit a corner.

Comment: Yeah, the ball hits a corner(usually when coming from the top back to the bottom) and can sometimes become completely horizontal.